# is it possible to give metamask a raw transaction to sign it and feed it back to us

Tags: metamask, web3.py

am building Dapp based on microservice and am testing something , to make Dapp more easier to use i, i decided to let metamask only sign a raw transaction , so the user will only do the steps of signup to the metamask ( no need to fix the network or anything else ) , so when you press a button from the front it will contract the  API , API will return a rawtransaction and the front will ask the metamask to sign the rawTransaction and feed it back to the front , then back to the API and the api will send the Raw Transaction and return the receipt , i finished Building the API ,

1- you will post related data that will be used with the contract in the API so you will POST to the API the right input (finished)

2- the API will build a transaction and it will return the RawTransaction ( finished )

3- the Front will catch the return and send it to the metamask ( kinda finished )

4- metamask will sign and return the value ( stuck here )

5- front will return to the API

6- the API will broadcast using the "sendRawTransaction"         ( finished )

any help or suggestion would help [image]

Comment: It is not possible with Metamask. See this issue https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/3475 for a discussion about the problems they had to deal while the feature was enabled.